# Excel - How to find number of times strings appear in column

Tags: excel, algorithm, excel-2016

This is my first post, I'm still a beginner at excel!

I created a python script that scrapes the Billboard Hip Hop/R&B Charts and populates the data to an excel spreadsheet. My data looks like this:

Headers are *Billboard Number, Artist Name* and *Song Title*.

```
1  Drake                                          Nice For What               
2  Post Malone Featuring Ty Dolla $ign            Psycho                      
3  Drake                                          God's Plan                  
4  Post Malone                                    Better Now                  
5  Post Malone Featuring 21 Savage                Rockstar                    
6  BlocBoy JB Featuring Drake                     Look Alive                  
7  Post Malone                                    Paranoid                    
8  Lil Dicky Featuring Chris Brown                Freaky Friday               
9  Post Malone                                    Rich & Sad                  
10 Post Malone Featuring Swae Lee                 Spoil My Night              
11 Post Malone Featuring Nicki Minaj              Ball For Me                 
12 Migos Featuring Drake                          Walk It Talk It             
13 Post Malone Featuring G-Eazy & YG              Same Bitches                
14 Cardi B| Bad Bunny & J Balvin                  I Like It                   
15 Post Malone                                    Zack And Codeine            
16 Post Malone                                    Over Now                    
17 Cardi B                                        Be Careful                  
18 Post Malone                                    Takin' Shots                
19 The Weeknd & Kendrick Lamar                    Pray For Me                 
20 Rich The Kid                                   Plug Walk                   
21 The Weeknd                                     Call Out My Name            
22 Bruno Mars & Cardi B                           Finesse                     
23 Post Malone                                    Candy Paint                 
24 Ella Mai                                       Boo'd Up                    
25 Rae Sremmurd & Juicy J                         Powerglide                  
26 Post Malone                                    92 Explorer                 
27 J. Cole                                        ATM                         
28 J. Cole                                        KOD                         
29 Post Malone                                    Otherside                   
30 Post Malone                                    Blame It On Me              
31 J. Cole                                        Kevin's Heart               
32 Kendrick Lamar & SZA                           All The Stars               
33 Nicki Minaj                                    Chun-Li                     
34 Lil Pump                                       Esskeetit                   
35 Migos                                          Stir Fry                    
36 Famous Dex                                     Japan                       
37 Post Malone                                    Sugar Wraith                
38 Cardi B Featuring Migos                        Drip                        
39 XXXTENTACION                                   Sad!                        
40 Jay Rock| Kendrick Lamar| Future & James Blake King's Dead                 
41 Rich The Kid Featuring Kendrick Lamar          New Freezer                 
42 Logic & Marshmello                             Everyday                    
43 J. Cole                                        Motiv8                      
44 YoungBoy Never Broke Again                     Outside Today               
45 Post Malone                                    Jonestown (Interlude)       
46 Cardi B Featuring 21 Savage                    Bartier Cardi               
47 YoungBoy Never Broke Again                     Overdose                    
48 J. Cole                                        1985 (Intro To The Fall Off)
49 J. Cole                                        Photograph                  
50 Khalid| Ty Dolla $ign & 6LACK                  OTW
```

I want to count the total number times an artist appears under *Artist Name* including if they were featured in a song and also display top charting song. For example:

Headers are *Artist Name, Billboard Appearances* and *Top Song*.

```
Post Malone                          17           Psycho
J.Cole                               6            ATM
Cardi B                              5            I Like It
Drake                                4            Nice For What
Migos                                3            Walk It Talk It
YoungBoy Never Broke Again           2            Outside Today
Rich The Kid                         2            Plug Walk
21 Savage                            2            Rockstar
...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: welcome to stack. the best thing you can do is try to solve your problem based on your own research and then post what you've tried if it doesn't work. please review - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: also i support this research. that is some sad looking data, music industry

Comment: A place to start could be to create a separate list of all the artists, one to a cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all artist names, use `countif` and `vlookup` with `wildcard`.

[image]

ps. Make sure your artist names are correct. Your sample data `J.cole` didn't contain whitespace, it will return wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do what's called data cleaning to get a list of the artists on the billboards.

To get a list of the unique artists copy the list of your data to a new space on your spreadsheet. Then select all of your data and run the "Remove Duplicates" function (under the Data tab) selecting the artist column. This will give you a list of all the unique artists and give you their top song to boot.

Now all those X featuring Y artist "names" will be unique, so you will need to filter it down some more. Search for the "Featuring" linker word with the Find function and use that combined with the Left function to grab only the first artist. Something like this, `=IFERROR(LEFT(I3,FIND("Featuring",I3)-2),I3)`
This function uses the iferror function to pass through names that don't have the "Featuring" word. Then do the same thing on that resulting column for & and | and that will give you a pretty clean list of single artists.

To get the featured artists, do a similar thing using the Right function instead of the Left function.

After you get that clean list do the unique artists filter again to condense it down. From there you can use that with your vlookup or find functions to start counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query (Get & Transform Data) to manipulate your table:

```
let

    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbInput"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Source,
        {{"Billboard Number", Int64.Type}, 
         {"Artist Name", type text}, 
         {"Song Title", type text}}),

    #"Split Column by Delimiters" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        Table.TransformColumns(
            #"Changed Type",
            {{"Artist Name", Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter({"Featuring","|","&"}, QuoteStyle.None), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), 
            "Artist Name"),

    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(
        #"Split Column by Delimiters",
        {{"Artist Name", Text.Trim, type text}}),

    #"Artist Highest Position" = Table.Group(
        #"Trimmed Text", 
        {"Artist Name"}, 
        {{"Highest Position", each List.Min([Billboard Number]), 
        type number}}),

    #"Merge 1" = Table.NestedJoin(
        #"Artist Highest Position",
        {"Artist Name", "Highest Position"},
        #"Trimmed Text",
        {"Artist Name", "Billboard Number"},
        "Merged",
        JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    #"Highest Song" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Merge 1", "Merged", {"Song Title"}, {"Song Title"}),

    #"Artist Count" = Table.Group(
        #"Trimmed Text", 
        {"Artist Name"}, 
        {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),

    #"Merge 2" = Table.NestedJoin(
        #"Artist Count",
        {"Artist Name"},
        #"Highest Song",
        {"Artist Name"},
        "Merged",
        JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    #"Expanded Merged" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
        #"Merge 2", "Merged", {"Song Title"}, {"Song Title"}),

    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Merged",{{"Count", Order.Descending}})

in

    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Which gives the output:

[image: Output Table]

Comment: I changed `Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbInput"]}[Content],` to `Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Billboard_Hip_Hop_Charts"]}[Content],` and I get an error that says, `Expression.Error: The column 'Artist Name' of the table wasn't found.
Details:
    Artist Name'. Is there a way to fix this problem? This is my first time using Power Query.

Comment: What are your column names in table `Billboard_Hip_Hop_Charts` ? I used column names `{"Billboard Number", "Artist Name", "Song Title"}` - so if your column names are different from those, you need to change the references accordingly. And your source data table must be formatted as a ListObject table.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is cleaning the data to get a unique list of artist names.

Examining your list, it seems that when there are multiple artist names listed for a single song, they will be separated by `Featuring`, `&`, or `|`

If that is always the case, you can use a VBA macro to separate the names, and then use a Dictionary to collect a list of the names.

While you are creating that list, it is trivial to also obtain the Count of times the artist appears, and also the top rated song (which would be the song associated with the first instance of that name).

We utilize a User Defined Object (Class) to hold the information, and collect those objects into a Dictionary keyed to the artist name.

Note also that we read the worksheet data into a VBA array, and iterate through the array.  This usually runs an order of magnitude faster than iterating through the actual worksheet.

To obtain the report, we would then output the results onto a worksheet.

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit
'Class module **RENAME**: cArtist
Public Cnt As Long
Public Song As String
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub Artists()
    Dim dA As Dictionary, cA As cArtist
    Dim vSrc, vRes
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim V, W, X, Y, Z, A, B
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet6")
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet6")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 6)

Set dA = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    W = Split(vSrc(I, 1), "Featuring")
        For Each X In W
            Y = Split(X, "|")
                For Each Z In Y
                    A = Split(Z, "&")
                        For Each B In A
                            sKey = Trim(B)
                            Set cA = New cArtist
                            With cA
                                .Cnt = 1
                                .Song = Trim(vSrc(I, 2))
                            End With
                            If Not dA.Exists(sKey) Then
                                dA.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cA
                            Else
                                dA(sKey).Cnt = dA(sKey).Cnt + 1
                            End If
                        Next B
                Next Z
        Next X
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To dA.Count, 1 To 3)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Artist Name"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Billboard Appearances"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Top Song"

I = 0
For Each V In dA.Keys
    I = I + 1
    With dA(V)
        vRes(I, 1) = V
        vRes(I, 2) = .Cnt
        vRes(I, 3) = .Song
    End With
Next V

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Sort key1:=rRes(1, 2), order1:=xlDescending, key2:=rRes(1, 1), order2:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False, Header:=xlYes
    .Style = "Output"
    With .Columns(2)
        .ColumnWidth = .ColumnWidth / 2
        .WrapText = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

**Output given your Input above**

[image]

Comment: This is my first time using VBA Macros, I noticed in the second line of the **Class Module** that you have RENAME text. Should I rename it to the name of my excel document?

Comment: @Fedolodic No, you need to rename the class module: from the default name (usually `Class1`) to  `cArtist`.  Examine the class module `Properties` and you will see a line labelled `(Name)`.  You can edit that line and change the Name to `cArtist`

Comment: I changed Class1 to cArtist and added the code in for **Class Module** and **Regular Module** and after trying to run I get the error _Compile error: User-defined type not defined_. Then in the **Regular Module** _Sub Artists()_ is highlighted in yellow in line 3 and _dA As Dictionary_ is highlighted in blue in line 4. I'm not sure what to change here

Comment: @Fedolodic Sorry.  Forgot to mention that you must set a reference -- (See `Tools/References` in the menu bar)  to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`